# Classes in Python 3: with/without self

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, methods

Considering that unbound methods are deprecated in Python 3, can someone please explain the difference between these two classes in terms of their advantages (if any) over each other? Which one is better for what purpose?

```
#Class Number 1
class SomeClass():
    a_cls_attribute = []

    def modify_a_cls_attribute(elem):
        SomeClass.a_cls_attribute.append(elem)

    def display_a_cls_attribute():
        print(SomeClass.a_cls_attribute)

SomeClass.modify_a_cls_attribute('elem')
SomeClass.display_a_cls_attribute()


#Class Number 2
class SomeClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.an_inst_attribute = []

    def modify_an_inst_attribute(self, elem):
        self.an_inst_attribute.append(elem)

    def display_an_inst_attribute(self):
        print(self.an_inst_attribute)

an_inst = SomeClass()
an_inst.modify_an_inst_attribute('elem')
an_inst.display_an_inst_attribute()
```

Edit:

In Python2, the class number 1 would be:

```
class SomeClass():
    a_cls_attribute = []

    @classmethod
    def modify_a_cls_attribute(cls, elem):
        cls.a_cls_attribute.append(elem)

    @classmethod     
    def display_a_cls_attribute(cls):
        print(cls.a_cls_attribute)

SomeClass.modify_a_cls_attribute('elem')
SomeClass.display_a_cls_attribute()
```

Comment: Why use a class *at all* in number 1? You are just namespacing functions there. I'd use a module for that instead.

Comment: Maybe for structuring otherwise a complex code? After all, this is just a fabricated code. I am trying to understand the merits of using class attributes/methods or instance attributes/methods.

Comment: But you can accomplish the exact same thing using a module, without upsetting expectations about what classes are normally used for.

Comment: :) Isn't it actually also true for the second class? I mean, certainly the second class, too, can be evaded in favor of a simple module. I am just trying to contrast class methods to instance methods, considering that the class number 1 is no more a syntactic error in Python 3.

Comment: If you need to pass around a singleton manager, then creating an instance of a class can be helpful over a module, as it documents the purpose better. The unbound vs. bound distinction wasn't removed to enable the first pattern, it was removed because it made little sense.

Comment: Unbound methods are deprecated in 2.7, where they are still present.  In 3.x, they are gone. not-existent.  In # 1, you are using the functions as functions, the same as if you had decorated them with `@staticmethod`.  Class methods, decorated with `@classmethod`, receive the class as the first parameter. It is often named `cls`.

Comment: Martijn Pieters and Terry Jan Reedy, thank you very much for your explanations. I removed my previous comment, because I noticed that I confused static methods with class methods. Thanks to your explanations, I understand them better now.